# How to force FlowDocument refresh its content on DataContext set?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use FlowDocument with bindings to have separate template which is able to be filled with actual data from data model. Then I convert it to image and print or save on hard-drive.
For binding FlowDocument's Runs with data model I use the code from this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx

The FlowDocument template is following:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
          xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Labels;assembly=DataModel.Impl"
PageWidth="200" MinPageWidth="200" PageHeight="200" MinPageHeight="200">

<Section>
  <Paragraph>
    <p:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
  </Paragraph>
</Section>

</FlowDocument>
```

Code for BindableRun:

```
public class BindableRun : Run
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BoundText", typeof(string), typeof(BindableRun),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, OnBoundTextChanged, CoerceText));

    public BindableRun()
    {
      FlowDocumentHelpers.FixupDataContext(this);
    }

    private static void OnBoundTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      ((Run)d).Text = (string)e.NewValue;
    }

    private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
      return value;
    }

    public String BoundText
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(BoundTextProperty); }
      set { SetValue(BoundTextProperty, value); }
    }
  }
```

Then I load template and set DataContext in it:

```
private class DataClass
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

private static FlowDocument LoadFlowDocument(string path)
{
  using (var xamlFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    return XamlReader.Load(xamlFile) as FlowDocument;
  }
}

    private static void FlowDoc2Image(FlowDocument document, DataClass dataContext, Stream imageStream)
{
  var flowDocumentScrollViewer = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer
  {
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden,
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden,
    DataContext = dataContext
  };

  flowDocumentScrollViewer.Document = document;

  flowDocumentScrollViewer.Measure(new Size(999999999, 999999999));

  //1st pass
  flowDocumentScrollViewer.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, flowDocumentScrollViewer.ActualWidth, flowDocumentScrollViewer.ActualHeight));
  //2nd pass. It's not code duplication! Do not remove!
  flowDocumentScrollViewer.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, flowDocumentScrollViewer.ActualWidth, flowDocumentScrollViewer.ActualHeight));

  var bitmapRenderer =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)flowDocumentScrollViewer.ActualWidth, (int)flowDocumentScrollViewer.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

  bitmapRenderer.Render(flowDocumentScrollViewer);

  var pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder { Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.On };
  pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapRenderer));

  pngEncoder.Save(imageStream);
}

public void Test()
{
  var doc = LoadFlowDocument("C:\\Experiments\\DocWithBinding.xaml");

  var context = new DataClass {Text = "SomeText"};
  doc.DataContext = context;

  using (var imageStream = new FileStream("C:\\Experiments\\image.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    FlowDoc2Image(doc, context, imageStream);
  }
}
```

But nothing happens. I tried to set break points in BindableRun on changing it's value. And I never get there. Changing DataContext doesn't affect the document.

Comment: Start by setting breakpoint on Getter and Setter of boundtext property and tell us first if they are being called.

Comment: @John Peters Yes, it's what I meant when I wrote "I tried to set break points in BindableRun on changing it's value." So I set breakpoints on Getter and Setter, but no reaction.

Comment: The getter and setter of the CLR wrapper of a dependency property are bypassed by WPF when the property is accessed in XAML. So any possible breakpoint will not be hit. See [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for details.

Comment: @Clemens Getter and Setter properties of the CLR wrapper are most certainly breakable at any time there's a change, in addition, another property can be seen in the OnBoundTextChange method too.

Comment: @Clemens You are right to some degree but not absolutely correct.  Sometimes WPF will not call the Getter Setter but sometimes it does, however it will always call the in his case the OnTextPropertyChaged unless of course the binding isn't correct which is the root cause of this issue.

Comment: @Clemens Clearly to me none of the suggestions above had any bearing on root cause of the solution.  It's irritating to me that folks want to get into cat fights about perfection when they aren't even on the right track.  I've posted the correct path to the solution in answer below for the op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need anymore for the BindableRun class. From the Remarks section in [`Run.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.text.aspx):

> Starting in the .NET Framework 4, the Text property of the Run object
>   is a dependency property, which means that you can bind the Text
>   property to a data source.

So your FlowDocument file could look like this:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    PageWidth="200" MinPageWidth="200" PageHeight="200" MinPageHeight="200">
    <Section>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </Section>
</FlowDocument>
```

I've loaded this like shown in your question, assigned a DataClass instance to its DataContext and sucessfully displayed it in a RichTextBox:

```
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private class DataClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var doc = LoadFlowDocument("DocWithBinding.xaml");
    doc.DataContext = new DataClass { Text = "Hello, World." };
    rtb.Document = doc;
}

private static FlowDocument LoadFlowDocument(string path)
{
    using (var xamlFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return XamlReader.Load(xamlFile) as FlowDocument;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** Although you are able to successfully put the FlowDocument into a FlowDocumentScrollViewer, it appears that synchronously rendering this viewer into a RenderTargetBitmap does not create the desired output. It feels like the binding is not yet established, as hard-coded text in the document will render synchronously.

I've tried a few things, but I can't seem to get around adding a short delay before rendering to the bitmap. I did this by making the `FlowDoc2Image` method async and calling `await Task.Delay(100)`. It is a hack, but it creates the PNG.

```
private async Task FlowDoc2Image(
    FlowDocument document, DataClass dataContext, Stream imageStream)
{
    var flowDocumentScrollViewer = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer
    {
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden,
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden,
        Document = document,
        DataContext = dataContext,
    };

    flowDocumentScrollViewer.Measure(
        new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
    flowDocumentScrollViewer.Arrange(new Rect(flowDocumentScrollViewer.DesiredSize));

    await Task.Delay(100);

    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)flowDocumentScrollViewer.DesiredSize.Width,
        (int)flowDocumentScrollViewer.DesiredSize.Height,
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

    renderTargetBitmap.Render(flowDocumentScrollViewer);

    var pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder { Interlace = PngInterlaceOption.On };
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
    pngEncoder.Save(imageStream);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's good news! I removed BindableRun and binded my data model directly with Run. But still the result is the same. After DataContext set I watched in debugger the state of Run.Text, it equals "". When I saved FlowDocument to the file, I've got the following:

`<FlowDocument PageWidth="200" MinPageWidth="200" PageHeight="200" MinPageHeight="200" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
 <Section>
  <Paragraph />
 </Section>
</FlowDocument>`

Comment: No idea what you are actually doing with the FlowDocument after setting its DataContext. However, putting it in a RichTextBox would make it display correctly.

Comment: Ok, for experiment I created an instance of RichTextBox just in code and passed to it my FlowDocument instance and my data model instance as DataContext. Looks like that RichTextBox somehow triggers FlowDocument to get actual data from data model. Perfect! But unfortunately it fails with exception: "BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object'" 
So do I have to create DataTemplate for my DataClass in FlowDocument xaml? And how can I apply it then? In WPF I would use ContentControl and ContentTemplate property in it. But what about FlowDocument?

Comment: Well, for some unknown reason my FlowDocument still doesn't really binds to data model. Even that exception with binding disappeared after some test runs without changes in code! Will look for alternatives.
But anyway thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Doesn't help. It looks like @John Peters suggestion below makes sense. But still is not as clear as binding in WPF.

Comment: While that other suggestion will also work, it doesn't mean that your initial approach is wrong. Binding `Text="{Binding Text}"` with a DataContext set to `new DataClass { Text = "Hello, World." };` creates a perfectly valid binding. I'm sure the fact that it doesn't show up on your side (and you get exceptions) has got to do with some part of your application that you haven't shown in your question.

Comment: I edited my question, so now you can see the full code with usage of FlowDocument.

Comment: Very interesting! So binding is being set asynchronously but without any public API for synchronization, isn't it? Ok, will think about it. I've almost implemented some kind of extension to FlowDocument which substitutes normal binding. It's tedious but at least straightforward and has no hacks. :))
Thanks a lot for your investigation! It gave me much to think about.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really the binding or perhaps some asynchronous document loading mecanism inside the viewer control. I could however not find any syncing event in FlowDocumentScrollViewer either.